# Karma-Jasmine with AngularJS realtime project

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have gone through several tutorials but none could really help me out.

I have also read through the documentation, which is easy for beginner test cases like to test for an array/string, etc. But i need some help in using it in a full-time project.

How to write these unit tests for not-so-simple cases like, matching what is displayed on the website is what should be expected?

Thanks!

Comment: so you are looking @e2e test

Comment: Take a look at 'protractor'

Comment: Not e2e test. But basic unit tests on the code. And also isnt it possible with karma-jasmine?